# What happens when a user removes my app from Facebook via the "Apps and websites" settings and tries to reconnect in my app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, facebook-php-sdk

So I've seen many related questions but they all date from years ago (Facebook SDK changes constantly) and mine is more specific.

I'm building a web app which requires authentication and Facebook API is one of its auth solutions and I'm trying to catch some scenarios. So as I asked earlier, *what happens when someone removes my app from Facebook via the "Apps and websites" settings and tries to reconnect in my app ?*

It might seem obvious to some that the user wouldn't get logged in because as far as I know in 2021, FB SDK uses an app specific ID for each user which gets generated when logging in for the first time and is useless when the user removes the app from his settings because there's no more mapping between the ID and the user.

**But** I've experienced in an app that I used (ometv kinda similar to omegle) that they log you in even after you delete them from the Facebook settings.

Thanks for considering my question.

**EDIT:** This is the edge case that I'm referring to from [facebook dev](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/testing-your-login-flow)

> 5. Someone removes your app from Facebook via app settings and revisits your app. Your app should detect this and prompt the person
>    to log back in. Go to your app and tap on the "Log in with Facebook”
>    button Tap OK to accept the read permissions (and OK again to accept
>    write permissions where applicable) Go to app settings on Facebook and
>    remove your app Repeat steps 1-2 and verify that Facebook Login works

A more specific question that I might ask would be whether or not a user can bypass this behavior ?

Comment: Bypass what behavior? No the user of course need to grant permission again if you want a Facebook access token. You can of course let the user in again if you know who they are but you don't get a Facebook access token

Comment: I was referring to them being able to remove our app from the Facebook settings not making them unable to authenticate. Can users of my app, by deleting it or their cookies, changing their name, email or any information from their account, be unable to authenticate ?

Comment: It depends on what your app uses to identify them. That should be the app-scoped user id (it won't change, if they remove your app, and reconnect to it later), but some platforms might use stuff like the email address instead, so if they changed that, you'd have trouble recognizing them again.

Comment: Okay so the app-scoped user id is persistent, right? It should persist even after a user removes my app. It doesn't feel like it when reading the docs thought, do you have any sources that clearly point that out ?